# return a dictionary of dictionaries flask and angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am creating an app using flask and ionic(angular) and I am trying to return a JSON of the list
currently my python code is the following

```
def get-stocks():
# Select all stocks 
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM `tbl_symbol_index`""")
stocks = cursor.fetchall()
stockList = []
data = {}
for stock in stocks:
    symbol = stock[0]
    companyName = stock[1]
    stockList.append({
        "symbol": symbol,
        "companyName": companyName
    })
data = {'stocks': stockList}
print(len(data["stocks"]))
return jsonify(data)
```

This returns the following dictionary.

```
data = {"stocks": [
         "Symbol": "TSLA",
         "companyName": "Tesla Inc"
          ],
          [
         "Symbol": "MSFT",
         "companyName": "Microsoft"
          ],
          [
         "Symbol": "AAPL",
         "companyName": "Apple"
          ],
}
```

I call that function from my angular using

```
ngOnInit() {
// Get a list of all existing stocks
const Stocks = this.initializeItems();
```

}

```
  async initializeItems(){
    this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-stocks").subscribe(function(data) {
    })
  }
```

but for some reason I cannot loop through it in my HTML

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let data of Stocks | filter:filterTerm">
    <ion-label>{{data.symbol}}</ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{data.companyName}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
@Component(...)
export class Component {
 data;
 ngOnInit() {
  // Get a list of all existing stocks
  this.initializeItems();
 }
 initializeItems(){
    this.http.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get-stocks").subscribe(datas => {
       this.data = datas;
        console.log(this.data.stocks)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still unable to view stocks when I do `console.log(Stocks);` it prints that `ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: undefined}
__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value: undefined
Symbol(Symbol.species): (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
__proto__: Object`

Comment: Sorry i've updated my response it should be beter

Comment: Thank you very much I just had to add ["stocks"] for the this.data = datas; line to make it equal to the key of stocks